# Modifier 'const' is not applicable to 'local variable', why?

Tags: android, kotlin, scope, constants

When I try put the `const val` like this:

```
const val DRAWABLE_RIGHT : Int = 2
```

inside a method, I get the error:

> Modifier 'const' is not applicable to 'local variable'

And when I move this `const val` to the top of class like this:

```
class MyClass @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context) : ConstraintLayout(context) {
    const val DRAWABLE_RIGHT : Int = 2
    ...
}
```

the compiler say that it's still incorrect:

> Const 'val' are only allowed on top level or in objects

**What does it mean `top level`?**

Answer (score 2):

Top Level means that you should put the variable outside of the class.

It is also possible to put it inside a companion object.

Comment: Top level means outside any class definition. The message says "or in objects" to describe the other allowed case. Calling the members of an object "top level" would be incorrect.

Comment: "It is also possible to put it inside a companion object." Not just companion.